# WPF Add a Border to a TextBlock

Tags: wpf

Is it possible to add a border to a textblock. I need it to be added in the setter property below code:

```
<Style x:Key="notCalled" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2,2,2,2" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
</Style>
```

Comment: Use a TextBox instead.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

You need to wrap your TextBlock in a Border. Example:

```
<Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
    <TextBlock ... />
</Border>
```

Of course, you can set these properties (`BorderThickness`, `BorderBrush`) through styles as well:

```
<Style x:Key="notCalledBorder" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
</Style>

<Border Style="{StaticResource notCalledBorder}">
    <TextBlock ... />
</Border>
```

Answer (score 37):

A TextBlock does not actually inherit from Control so it does not have properties that you would generally associate with a Control. Your best bet for adding a border in a style is to replace the TextBlock with a Label

See [this link](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/07/04/differences-between-label-and-textblock/) for more on the differences between a TextBlock and other Controls

Comment: Great info at that link which I didn't know.  I prefer this as @Heinzi's solution doesn't work in my app.  Despite trying that solution, no border displays.

Comment: I was banging my head against the wall because of this. I also have come to the idea to replace `TextBlock` with `Label`, but guess what: `Label` does not support format strings in the binding. In XAML, you can add format strings to label bindings without causing syntax errors, and the thing compiles and runs without exceptions. However, the labels just don't care about the format string in their binding. Therefore I had to go the route to wrap the `TextBlock` in a `Border`. Quite a mess ...

Answer (score 0):

```
<Label Name="Lbl_IP2"  Style="{StaticResource LabelWithBorder}" Content="3"/>

<Style TargetType="Label" x:Key="LabelWithBorder">
  <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,5,10,5"/>
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="#202020"/>
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#fff"/>
  <Setter Property="Width" Value="auto"/>
  <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
  <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
  <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
  <Setter Property="FlowDirection" Value="LeftToRight"/>

  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
        <Border SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Background="#000" BorderBrush="AliceBlue" BorderThickness="1" Padding="5">
          <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" RecognizesAccessKey="True">
            <ContentPresenter.Effect>
              <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="15" Direction="-90" RenderingBias="Quality" ShadowDepth="2" Opacity="0.3"/>
            </ContentPresenter.Effect>
          </ContentPresenter>
        </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Usage:

```
<Label Name="Lbl_IP2"  Style="{StaticResource LabelWithBorder}" Content="3"/>
```