# Add border into my TextBlock Style

Tags: wpf

I have this style:

```
<Style x:Key="labelStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
</Style>
```

I am using this `style` over my chart `SmartLabel` and i want to add border.
Any suggestions ?

Comment: Can i have code example ?

Comment: Please view [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970522/wpf-add-a-border-to-a-textblock) answer

Answer (score 1):

wrap the Textblock inside a Border:

```
<Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
    <TextBlock ... />
</Border>
```

You can use other properties on the border too, like `BorderBrush`, `Thikness` and so on

Answer (score 0):

you can override template of textblock .put one border in its template and a textblock for borders child.

Comment: That was my first suggestion. But TextBlock has no template

Comment: So what is my options ?

Comment: @berrywer Add TextBlock inside Border.

Comment: And after that ? i need style with TargetType="TextBlock"