# Adding border to entire grid when I'm trying to add it to only a TextBlockC#

Tags: c#, xaml

I'm trying to add a border to only a TextBlock but instead it is creating it around the entire grid. Here is the code :

```
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="6">
    <TextBlock x:Name="txtInputUsername" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="65,54,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Username" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Open Sans" FontSize="20" Background="#FFF3F3F3" OpacityMask="Black"/>
</Border>
```

Comment: [Try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970522/wpf-add-a-border-to-a-textblock)

Comment: try `Styles` and target TextBlock, and use the style in ur TextBlock

Comment: @un-lucky, isn't that what I did? Wrapped the TextBlock with a Border.

Comment: @Raizzen I'm sorry but I'm new to C# and didn't quite get what you're trying to say...

Comment: @Isonlaxman dw iam kinda new to it too. but its basically that what un-lucky posted. learning by doin is the answer, search for "xaml Styles" u will find alot, try it, if u fail dw, ask :D

Comment: @Isonlaxman added btw the answer, this should work :D

Comment: Your code appears to be okay, except for the `Margin` thing. Remove `Margin` attribute and it will just wrap the `TextBlock`.

Comment: Children directly inside a grid take the `Height` and `Width` of the grid (or cell, if they are in a grid cell).  Your `Border` is not actually going around the `Grid`, it is just getting automatically sized to the same size as the `Grid`.  Try a `StackPanel` instead, or one of the other layout containers.  Also, try to avoid using `Margin` to position things.  Layout contains are the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because child elements of a `Grid` will assume the `Height` and `Width` of the `Grid` (or the `Grid` cell) they are placed in, unless otherwise specified.  The `Border` just *looks* like it is wrapping around the grid, because it is using it to infer its size.

There are a few ways to fix this, with the easiest being to specify the `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` of the `Border` to  `Center`. This causes the `Border` to snap around the bounds of the `TextBlock` instead of inferring its size.

In your case, it still produces some odd results because of your use of `Margin` to position the label. The `Margin` is still counted as being part of the control, so anything the wraps around the control will have to be larger to accommodate it.  You should avoid that if at all possible, but if you *really* want to do it that way, more the `Margin` to the `Border`.

```
<Grid>
    <Border
        Margin="65,54,0,0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        BorderBrush="Black"
        BorderThickness="6">
        <TextBlock
            x:Name="txtInputUsername"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Background="#FFF3F3F3"
            FontFamily="Open Sans"
            FontSize="20"
            OpacityMask="Black"
            Text="Username"
            TextAlignment="Center"
            TextWrapping="Wrap" />
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

[image: Screenshot]

---

A better way to handle this though, is to learn about the different [layout containers](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140613/WPF-Tutorial-Layout-Panels-Containers-Layout-Trans), and how to use them to position your controls, instead of `Margin`.  These can be nested within each other to create almost any layout you can imagine, in a fairly nice, clean way.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I was up late trying to fix it and slept for like ages after struggling with it. Why does it have to be so complicated :(

Comment: It gets easier the more you work with it. Don't give up!