# How can I turn on both vertical and horizontal borders for the itemTemplate Control?

Tags: wpf, xaml, border, itemscontrol

I created the item template control and set its border thickness and color in Data Template. This is my ItemTemplate code:

```
  <ItemsControl  x:Name="VimshottariDasha" Margin="-10,83,-124,-267" FontSize="16" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" BorderThickness="0">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="DimGray">

                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Col1" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Col2" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Col3" />
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                            <Button Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" x:Name="DashaButton" Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding rulerName}" Command="{Binding SelectedDasha}" CommandParameter="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
                                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding rulerStartDate, StringFormat=dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss}"  />
                                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding rulerEndDate, StringFormat=dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss}"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Border>
                                </DataTemplate>

                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

How do I show both vertical and horizontal borders regardless of stack orientation?

The same thing happens in another itemTemplate but in reverse, whose stack orientation is set to Horizontal. I can see vertical borders in the second item Control but no Horizontal borders.

[This is the current Output, it has horizontal Borders inside but no vertical ones(Stack orientation is vertical by default)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brvbZ.png)

[This is second ItemControl with horizontal stack orientation it is missing horizontal borders.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHhzX.png)

Thanks.

Comment: Are you really expecting to see a border between the Button and the two TextBlock controls?

Comment: Mmmm.. yes.. it is possible .. isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First go through this [link to understand how to add border around TextBlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970522/wpf-add-a-border-to-a-textblock).

You can also use Label instead of TextBlock to add border.

Now look into modified code:

```
ItemsControl Grid.Row="0" x:Name="VimshottariDasha" Margin="10" FontSize="16" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

            <DataTemplate>
                <!--<Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="DimGray">-->

                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Col1" />
                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Col2" />
                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Col3" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Button Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="1" x:Name="DashaButton" Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding rulerName}" />
                        <Border Grid.Column="1" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Blue">
                            <TextBlock   Text="{Binding rulerStartDate, StringFormat=dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss}"  />
                        </Border>
                        
                        <Label BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Bisque" Grid.Column="2" Content="{Binding rulerEndDate, StringFormat=dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss}"/>
                    </Grid>
                <!--</Border>-->
            </DataTemplate>

        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Thanks aansari. I changed both textBlock to labels and set their border with horizontal content alignment as center. It works wonder. Exactly what I needed. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

A WPF [Border](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.border?view=netframework-4.8) control only draws the border along its outer edges. [It is possible to turn of one or more edges by setting its [BorderThickness](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.border.borderthickness?view=netframework-4.8).]

If you want to create border lines between individual controls, you either have to use multiple Border elements, or manually draw the internal lines yourself.

For example

```
<Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="2" >
    <Grid Height="24" >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Column 1" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="Column 2" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Text="Column 3" VerticalAlignment="Center" />

        <Path Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="1" Data="M 0,0 M 2,2 M 1,0 L 1,2" Stretch="Fill" Grid.Column="1" />
        <Path Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="1" Data="M 0,0 M 2,2 M 1,0 L 1,2" Stretch="Fill" Grid.Column="3" />
    </Grid>
</Border>
```